# Backward schema migration in Django South - CharField max_length conflict?

Tags: django, django-models, django-south

I change `max_length` of `CharField` in my model and South generates migration with this `forward` and `backward` migrate behaviour. So if I migrate it forward, then add some 1000-letters word in the field, and then migrate model backward, will all be ok? Or maybe I need to add some trimming commands in backward migration to prevent any DB errors?

There is a part of migration:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    # Changing field 'Unit.founders'
    db.alter_column('unit', 'founders', 
                    self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(
                        max_length=1000, null=True))

def backwards(self, orm):
    # Changing field 'Unit.founders'

    db.alter_column('unit', 'founders', 
                    self.gf('django.db.models.fields.CharField')(
                    max_length=250, null=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, everything will be fine as long as you using one of default db drivers.
Actually, You can test it faster then post question to stackoverflow. :-)